# are they ways to shorten up the do and while statement?

Tags: visual-c++

thank you for the time reading my question. I was just wondering, are there anyway to shorten this up;

```
int nextValue;
int PreValue;
Do               // I wanna shorten this up without looping it.
{
 cout << "please put something that is greater than the previous value:";
 cin >> nextValue
 }
 while ( nextValue < preValue);
```

sorry for the noob question, still trying to learn c++

Comment: Are you really looking to just reduce the number of lines from 6 to something with fewer lines? What do you mean "shorten this up without looping it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not by much. Your solution is 8 lines of code (which is pretty small to begin with) and that code could even be condensed realistically into 5 lines based on preference...

```
int nextValue, preValue;
do { 
   cout << "please put something that is greater than the previous value:";
   cin >> nextValue;
} while ( nextValue < preValue);
```

However, I think you could get away with using a regular while loop in your example. `preValue` needs to be *initialized* to something so your comparison can give you reliable results. The way it is now, `preValue` could be -454234, 7654, 1, 0... we don't know what it is; it hasn't been initialized. Initialize it, and then use a regular while loop. By initialize, I mean *explicitly assigning it a value*.

```
int nextValue = 0, preValue = INT_MIN;
while (preValue < nextValue){ 
   cout << "please put something that is greater than the previous value:";
   cin >> nextValue;
}
```

---

If you want to get a value without using a loop, an alternative is to define a function and call it recursively.

```
int getValue(int minValue){
    int input;
    std::cout << "please put something that is greater than the previous value:";
    std::cin >> input;

    input > minValue ? return input: return getValue(minValue);
}

value = getValue(preValue);
```

Shortening the solution is definitely possible (you could technically put it all on one line), but it's always good practice to try and make your code readable and understandable as possible. In my example, `getValue()` will continue to call itself until the user enters a value greater than the minimum. In the end, it's not much different in terms of lines of code, but it will leave which ever function you're prompting the user for input much shorter.

```
int main(){
    //other statements here. 

    int nextValue;
    int PreValue;
    Do               // I wanna shorten this up without looping it.
    {
    cout << "please put something that is greater than the previous value:";
    cin >> nextValue
    }
    while ( nextValue < preValue);

    //more statements here.
}
```

Becomes...

```
int main(){
    int minValue = 10; 
    //other statements.

    int value = getValue(minValue);
    //more statements
}
```

Obviously the recursive solution is more code than the 5 lines in the first example, but the advantage is it's now in its own function. If you'd need to prompt to user 5 different times, you'd only have to write `int value = getValue(min);` 5 times instead of the whole while loop 5 times.

Comment: Thank you. this has really been helpful for me practicing coding as efficient as possible.